# How to solve could not find function "get.hist.quote" issue?

Tags: r

```
GSPC <- as.xts(get.hist.quote("^GSPC",start="1970-01-02", quote=c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close","Volume","AdjClose")))
```

> Error in get.hist.quote("^GSPC", start = "1970-01-02", quote = c("Open",  : 
>     could not find function "get.hist.quote"

Comment: I guess `get.hist.quote` is from package `tseries`, have you installed the package and loaded in your environment with `library(tseries)`?

Comment: This works: `GSPC <- tseries::get.hist.quote(instrument="^GSPC", start= "1970-01-02", 
end="2020-01-31", quote=c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"), provider= "yahoo", compression="d", retclass="zoo")`

Comment: Already installed tseries. Nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you have a problem when calling function, you could have 2 different functions with different names of 2 different packages. So for example for *get.hist.quote()* you can call it in this way:

```
package1::get.hist.quote()
package2::get.hist.quote()
```